# Has my Android App been published to Production?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

As soon as I published the App, I received a message as below.

```
Your recent app updates have been published.

Users should see these changes immediately, but this can occasionally take longer
```

But it has already been more than 15 Hours and the App is not there in Prod; I can still see older version sadly.

My question are:

- How long does Google take to publish the App ?
- Pre-launch report found a issues in the App ? Can I (or the system) ignore this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would dare to answer my own question this time.

- How long does Google take to publish the App ?

> Answer: It claimed it could take upto 7 days but it took around 24Hrs for me. The rule of the thump is looking like if it is a major version release it usually it longer otherwise within 8Hrs (or upto 24Hrs) it finishes review.

- Pre-launch report found a issues in the App ? Can I (or the system) ignore this ?

> Yes, pre-launch report is only for notification to let the developer know if there is any error|warning|issue which Google ignore before publish.

Eventually, Google has published my App and is LIVE now.